# Pyhton OpenCv not opening webcam on pycharm windows

Tags: python, opencv, pycharm, webcam

I have tried every single solution... It's just not working.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

cv2.namedWindow("Window")

while True:
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()
    cv2.imshow("Window", frame)

    #This breaks on 'q' key
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The code runs fine even on terminal i couldn't find anything wrong. The file is running perfectly but the webcam is not opening. The webcam is upadted and internal webcam of my laptop. I tried cv2.videoCapture(-1) that's also not working.

The main problem is it's not opening the webcam window. Otherwise everything seems fine.

Using Python-3.11.0
Pycharm 2022 version
windows 10

I have installed openCV
I have installed mediapipe
I have installed CVzone

nothing is doing.

Comment: complete traceback required. please review [mre]

Answer (score 1):

You are calling

```
ret, frame = video_capture.read()
```

but video_capture has not been defined. You did define

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```

Comment: please vote to flag/close such questions as due to a ***typo***. this issue is syntactic. if OP had debugged their code, this would have been noticed.